# How file transfer work with realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've some queries related with realm file(mp3/jpeg/mp4) transfer:

1. Do we need to handle the file chunking at client side(mobile
   platform) if we've to transfer file to ROS?
2. How do realm transfer the file to ROS, in chunks or complete file itself.
3. If realm sync the file in chunks, what will be the result in case of connection break, will it start pushing the chunks from the 
   beginning or it will be an acknowledgement based process which will 
   resume the syncking from the last received chunk.
4. Does realm assure that no data corruption will take place while transferring file to ROS.
5. What could be the maximum size supported by realm?

Comment: I would advise against storing large objects in Realm as it's not really built for such use. It's built for storing relatively small objects.While it is possible to store large objects inside realm objects you might bump up against unexpected behavior